# name.cols command in Splus to R

Tags: r, matrix, s-plus

I have a code in Splus, but have to convert it into R, which is not a big thing. However I am very new to both softwares. This is the code I am struggling with:

```
 name.x<-name.cols(x)
```

`x` is a matrix of independent variables where first `length(keep1)` columns correspond to variables that are always kept in BMA (Bayesian Model Averaging -- this isn't important. Essentially, `x` is a matrix)

R does not recognize this command. What is name.cols doing, and how can I do the same thing in R? How do I modify this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `colnames` returns the column names of an object in R:

```
name.x <- colnames(x)
```

Comment: `names` works as well on a `data.frame` as in `names(mtcars)`.  This is because the `data.frame` is a `list` of equal length `lists`/`vectors`.  I got into the dirty habit of using `names` though early on and it bit me a number of times.  Best to be safe and use `colnames` as Sven suggests.